# Working in PyDev console , But not when running in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I am learning python with PythonCook Book. I came across a scenario and i dont know why this happens. The below code is working fine when i run it in PyDev console.

```
>>> user_record =('Dave', 'dave@example.com', '773-555-1212', '847-555-1212')
>>> name, email, *phone_numbers = user_record
>>> name
'Dave'
>>> email
'dave@example.com'
>>> phone_numbers
['773-555-1212', '847-555-1212']
```

But when i run the code in Eclipse , i get the following error like 'undefined variable name'

Whats the concept here ? i am really new to python

Comment: What python version(s) are you running on each?

Comment: @InbarRose python 3.4

Comment: For something small like this it is really easy to just throw it in a script file and run the file. That way you can keep track of everything you have done. Also, a very popular console environment is Ipython.

Comment: @JustinEngel i am getting this error when i run in a file. its working fine in pyDevConsole

Answer (score 1):

This is the file I ran. It works. I don't know why it is giving you an error unless you put ">>>" in the file.

```
def main():
    user_record = ('Dave', 'dave@example.com', '773-555-1212', '847-555-1212')
    name, email, *phone_numbers = user_record
    print(name)
    print(email)
    print(phone_numbers)
# end main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output:

```
Dave
dave@example.com
['773-555-1212', '847-555-1212']
```

Comment: i am using ">>>" in the question for letting others know that that i ran the code successfully in the python dev console. I run your code successfully in a file. But the eclipse still shows the red mark in the third line. That's what i was asking about.

Comment: The only other thing I can think that would be a problem is if you didn't have the interpreter configured correctly or put () around name, email, *phone_numbers. "(name, email, *phone_numbers) = user_record"